# Pandas: Create New Column using Values in Subgroup of Other Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with transactions. The index is the date of the transaction (timestamp), and the columns are the price (float), city (string), and product name (string). I want to add a new column to the dataframe containing the minimum price for each product in each city. So the fourth column will have the same value for every row where the city and product are the same.

Here's example code:

```
# dictionary of transactions

d = {'1': ['20', 'NYC', 'Widget A'], '2': ['30', 'NYC', 'Widget A'], '3': ['5', 'NYC', 'Widget A'], \
     '4': ['300', 'LA', 'Widget B'], '5': ['30', 'LA', 'Widget B'],  '6': ['100', 'LA', 'Widget A']}

columns=['Price', 'City', 'Product']

# create dataframe and rename columns

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=d, orient='index')
df.columns = columns
```

This produces a dataframe that looks like this

```
Price   City    Product

1   20  NYC Widget A

2   30  NYC Widget A

3   5   NYC Widget A

4   300 LA  Widget B

5   30  LA  Widget B

6   100 LA  Widget A
```

So I would want to add a new columns with the minimum price for each city/product subgroup. So rows 1-3 (all NYC/Widget A) would be 5 (the min price which is in row 3), Rows 4 and 5 would have a value of 30 (both LA/Widget B), and Row 6 would have a value of 100.

Comment: Please add some sample code and expected output, in order to reproduce your question.

Comment: To second that request, it's considered polite to add an example dataframe of input and output.  Otherwise people have to spend time making up their own examples, and sometimes it means that the examples people come up with differ from your real case in some way you didn't think to mention, which frustrates everybody.

Comment: Thanks guys. This is my first post so I wasn't aware of that. I just edited the post to include sample data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from a sample dataframe `product.csv` like this:

```
date,price,city,product
2015-09-21,1.5,c1,p1
2015-09-21,1.2,c1,p1
2015-09-21,0.5,c1,p2
2015-09-21,0.3,c1,p2
2015-09-22,0.6,c2,p2
2015-09-22,1.2,c2,p2
```

I would do in this way:

```
# Read Dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('product.csv')
```

Then I'm adding the desired column with:

```
df['minprice'] = df.groupby(['city','product'])['price'].transform(min)
```

which returns:

```
         date  price city product  minprice
0  2015-09-21    1.5   c1      p1       1.2
1  2015-09-21    1.2   c1      p1       1.2
2  2015-09-21    0.5   c1      p2       0.3
3  2015-09-21    0.3   c1      p2       0.3
4  2015-09-22    0.6   c2      p2       0.6
5  2015-09-22    1.2   c2      p2       0.6
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! That does help. It's actually a solution that I tried before posting this question. It worked on the example data but when I try to use it on my actual dataset, I get an error "ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 5221 elements, new values have 5247 elements". Must be some issue with my own dataset.

Comment: The problem was that in my dataset, some of the prices were NaN. That was causing a length mismatch. Problem solved. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider accepting one of the two answers if they help you in solving your task.

Comment: @FabioLamanna Hi. I would like to know what to do if I want to pass in an additional parameter to the function passed to `transform`? e.g. something like `transform(func, args=1)` (of course this doesn't work). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You need to apply `transform` to the `groupby`, which preserves the shape of your original DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'price': np.round(np.random.random(15), 2), 
                   'product': list('ABC') * 5, 
                   'city': ['San Francisco'] * 10 + ['New York'] * 5}

df['min_city_product_price'] = df.groupby(['city', 'product']).price.transform(min)

>>> df
             city  price product  min_city_product_price
0   San Francisco   0.65       A                    0.35
1   San Francisco   0.97       B                    0.28
2   San Francisco   0.09       C                    0.09
3   San Francisco   0.35       A                    0.35
4   San Francisco   0.28       B                    0.28
5   San Francisco   0.84       C                    0.09
6   San Francisco   0.49       A                    0.35
7   San Francisco   0.94       B                    0.28
8   San Francisco   0.13       C                    0.09
9   San Francisco   0.89       A                    0.35
10       New York   0.75       B                    0.30
11       New York   0.31       C                    0.31
12       New York   0.22       A                    0.22
13       New York   0.30       B                    0.30
14       New York   0.56       C                    0.31
```

Comment: Thanks! Another user provided the same solution so I'll reply with what I replied to him. This solution wrosk on the example data but when I try to use it on my actual dataset, I get an error "ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 5221 elements, new values have 5247 elements". Must be some issue with my own dataset.

Comment: The problem was that in my dataset, some of the prices were NaN. That was causing a length mismatch. Problem solved. Thanks again.